# Incomplete sylog log when thread exit

Tags: c, rsyslog

I ve a main program that initializes syslog, this program can run multiple threads, the problem is, when a thread exit, i find only a part of their logs in syslog file, what is the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

You should flush your buffers.

Comment: I ve googled longer time and there is no post flushing syslog buffer. i think that is impossible to do such thing.

Answer (score 0):

after some tests i ve found the solution, use LOG_EMERG instead of LOG_INFO or LOG_DEBUG, this will let syslog make great priority to the message, so my thread messages are no longer lost.